# Django urlresolvers reverse for dynamically generated ids

Tags: python, django

I've got to test URLs that look like this:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/pay/513623c9/

but I'm not sure how to say this to the `reverse()` function. This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from payment import views
from payment.msn import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^msnstats/', MsnStats.finish_transaction, name='finish_transaction'),
    url(r'^pay/(?P<payment_id>\w+)/$', views.pay, name='pay')
)
```

And this is what the relevant part of my views.py looks like:

```
def pay(request, payment_id):
    try:
        plan=PaymentPlan.objects.get(payment_id=payment_id)
```

The `payment_id` is generated for each plan, so I first create a plan, get its `payment_id` from the database, and somehow call it. I'm just not sure how to use reverse.

Comment: What *exactly* about the [documentation of `reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) is confusing?

Comment: I'm not sure which part of my URL is an 'argument' from reverse's point of view. What exactly gives you the right to be so snarky?

Comment: Not being snarky at all. I'm asking so that a) we can help you and b) we can improve the documentation if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
url = reverse('pay', args=[plan.payment_id])
```

or

```
url = reverse('pay', kwargs={'payment_id': plan.payment_id})
```

Both versions are valid.

**UPDATE**: If you include the `payment.urls` with `namespace` argument then you have to add this namespace to the url name in the `reverse()` call:

**project/urls.py**:

```
url(r'^payment/', include('payment.urls', namespace='payment')),
```

**payment/tests.py**:

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('payment:pay', args=[plan.payment_id]))
```

Comment: As it turns out, I had already written the first solution, but it didn't work, so I posted here. This is the test function:
 `def test_msn_payment_id(self):
  plan = create_payment_plan('lalala')
  response = self.client.get(reverse('pay', args=[plan.payment_id]))
  self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)`
Which fails with this:
`django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'pay' with arguments '('34ffb5d7',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

The payment_id is generated each time a new plan is created.

Comment: Django did move the reverse from urlresolvers to url for the newer version. You might want to change that if you are working with a later version of django.